# Importing a module, error with library functions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, typeerror

i'm currently using NodeJS.

I'm trying to import a module to a component function and everything executes pretty well, but i still get this error in the server console:

```
error - src\modules\accountFunctions.js (15:35) @ Object.User.GetData
TypeError: _cookieCutter.default.get is not a function
```

cookieCutter.get is actually a function and is working as inteneded

```
import cookieCutter from 'cookie-cutter'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { accountActions } from '../store/account'

const Auth = require('./auth.module')

const User = {}

User.GetData = async () => {
    const route = useRouter()
    const userData = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const sessionId = cookieCutter.get('session')

    if (sessionId && userData.username === '') {
        const userExist = await Auth.loadUserInformation()
        if (userExist.result === false) {
            route.push('/login')
            return false
        }
        dispatch(accountActions.updateAccountInformation(userExist.data))
        return true
    } else if (!sessionId) {
        route.push('/login')
        return false
    }
}

module.exports = User
```

I know for a fact that a solution would be importing the library into the function compoenent but i really don't wanna keep on importing it everywhere.

This is how i'm importing the module.

```
import User from '../src/modules/accountFunctions'

const dashboard = () => {
    console.log('Rance')
    User.GetData()
    return <NavBar />
}

export default dashboard
```

Comment: Also, this CommonJS <==> ESM compatibility has been regularly getting more options as node versions advance.  What version of nodejs are you running?  Here's a [discussion of options](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs) in v12 and apparently more was added in v14.

Comment: That didn't work, it's weird though because the function does work and i can print it and everything. It just prints the error when it shouldn't.

Comment: What version of nodejs?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're using the library correctly in nodejs.  It appears you have to call `cookieCutter(document)` to get an object that then has `.set()` and `.get()` methods on it.  That `document` object you pass needs to have a `.cookie` property with getters and setters that works like `document.cookie` in the browser.  This does not seem very useful within nodejs as you have to write a bunch of wrapper code to make it work.

Comment: FYI, the entire extent of this code is here: https://github.com/substack/cookie-cutter/blob/master/index.js.  There's not much to it and it has not been updated in 5 years.  You can see from that how you should be using it.

Comment: Do you have any other library to grabbing cookies that might work for NodeJS? I'm running V14.17.4

I'm also using NextJS 12

Comment: You're using Next.js so `User.GetData` is essentially a custom hook. You need to move the cookie fetching logic inside a `useEffect`. Calling `cookieCutter.get` won't work when Next.js pre-renders the page on the server.

Comment: Thank actually fixed it. Thank you so much @juliomalves. I'm now not sure how to mark your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the cookie fetching logic to a `useEffect` inside the custom hook, so it only runs on the client-side. Calling `cookieCutter.get` won't work when Next.js pre-renders the page on the server.

```js
const useUserData = async () => {
    const route = useRouter()
    const userData = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAuthenticatedUser = async () => {   
            const sessionId = cookieCutter.get('session')

            if (sessionId && userData.username === '') {
                const userExist = await Auth.loadUserInformation()
                if (userExist.result === false) {
                    route.push('/login')
                }
                dispatch(accountActions.updateAccountInformation(userExist.data))
            } else if (!sessionId) {
                route.push('/login')
            }
        }
        getAuthenticatedUser()
    }, [])
}
```